# ArcPy - Select by Location and Copy Features - Error 000732: Invalid Features

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, select-by-location, error-000732, result-object

I've been reading through some of the other answers but I haven't found a solution to my problem yet. I'm working with ArcMap in Python 2.7 in a standalone script.

I'm trying to select some features based on a two shapefiles in a given .mxd, and export the selection to a new featureclass or shapefile.

Currently my code lists the layers in my .mxd, creates the selection, and attempts to use the `CopyFeatures_management()` function - but I get the exception

```
ERROR 000732: Input Features: Dataset contaminated_land does not exist or is not supported
Failed to execute (MakeFeatureLayer).
```

Here is my code so far:

```
import arcpy, os, glob, arcpy.mapping as map

arcpy.env.workspace = "M:\GIS\Oscar\Land_Charges"

os.chdir(arcpy.env.workspace)

mxd_list = glob.glob('*.mxd')

mxd = mxd_list[0]
my_mxd = map.MapDocument(mxd)


for mxd in mxd_list: # Looping through all the .mxd's in a folder
    print mxd
    my_mxd = map.MapDocument(mxd)

frame_list = map.ListDataFrames(my_mxd)
df = frame_list[0]

activeframe = my_mxd.activeDataFrame

layers_list = map.ListLayers(my_mxd,'*',df)

test_poly = layers_list[0]
#test_poly = "M:\GIS\Oscar\Land_Charges\land_charges.gdb\\test_poly"
contaminated_land = layers_list[3]

select = arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management(contaminated_land,
                                                'WITHIN',
                                                test_poly,
                                                None,
                                                'NEW_SELECTION'
                                                )

arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(select, 'contam_select')

arcpy.Delete_management('contaminated_land_select.shp')

arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(select, 'contaminated_land_select.shp')
```

What I am confused about is the contaminated_land shapefile works okay in the `SelectLayerByLocation_management()` function, but then tells me that it is invalid for `MakeFeatureLayer_management()` or `CopyFeatures_management()`?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Geoprocessing tools return [result objects](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/classes/result.htm). So what you are calling `select` is a result object, you would query that for the actual output which would be a count. If count is non-zero then you would act on it.

All tools honor selections so no need to make a new feature layer, simply just feed the layer with the selection into the next tool. That would be `contaminated_land`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer - I was really confused about what the geoprocessing tools returned and couldn't find the documentation.

The shapefile returned seems to have no attributes, though when I change the select by location method to 'INTERSECT', the new selection shapefile returns the entire contaminated_land shapefile instead.

Comment: I found the solution to my select problem so I'll put it here for reference: I reset the spatial index (because my inputs were shapefiles rather than feature classes), and then I found that one of my polygons was a multipart polygon. After using the 'explode multipart features polygon' the intersection seemed to work okay.

https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/216287/the-select-by-location-tool-of-arcmap-wont-work-properly